# How to sort hashes in an array by keys?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Eg:

```
arr = ["c", "e", "a", {"hello" => [1,2,3]}, {"bell" => [4,5,6]}]
```

Above variable refers to an array which contains hashes along with strings. I need to write a function to sort this array alphabetically while the hashes being sorted by keys. Ideally it has to return the following:

```
["a", {"bell" => [4,5,6]}, "c", "e", {"hello" => [1,2,3]}]
```

Comment: What will happen if the hash has several keys?

Comment: No it's always gonna be single key-value pair hash

Comment: This is a pure-Ruby question so it should not have a Rails tag. The “arrays” and “hash” tags are only useful if someone is searching on them, which is questionable because they rarely appear as tags in questions that involve such common objects. There’s nothing wrong with having just a Ruby tag for a general Ruby question. When clarifying in response to a comment it’s best to edit the question rather than answering in a comment.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Noted. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array.sort_by {|a| a.is_a?(Hash) ? a.keys.first : a }
```